# Add object into WPF listview with ItemContainerStyle

Tags: wpf, listview, itemcontainerstyle

I have a listview, with ItemContainerStyle, call StyleA.

the listview has itemSource of an ObservableCollection, which contain my class objects. StyleA will bind to the property of my class object according to my template.

It works properly.

Now I want to include a textbox into the listview, like this:

```
<ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource StyleA}">
    <TextBox Text="Hello World"/>
</ListView>
```

It's not working, because StyleA can't bind with the class object's property. (because it is TextBox).

I had tried `<TextBox OverrideDefaultStyle="True" Text="Hello World"/>`, but same error too.

Any help?

Comment: what are you trying to do by adding a textbox like that?

Comment: Because I want to have an effect like, when user want to rename it, it can become a textbox, and let user to key in new value, then save it.

Comment: So you need TextBox inside an item? Then you should use ItemTemplate instead of ItemContainerStyle. You can put TextBox inside template, bind its Text to item's name, and change its visibility when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is, I use a Label to contain a TextBlock, and when I need to modified the text, I change the content of Label into TextBox, set the TextBlock's text into TextBox, so I can modify the text, after Enter key, save the text, and change Label content to TextBlock again.

Maybe not an elegant solution, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [ItemContainerStyleSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyleselector.aspx) to apply different item styles.